# Redux, calling another action case statement depending on outcome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm creating a packing list for a holiday.

I have these 2 cases:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case 'ADD_ITEM': {
    const items = [].concat(state.items).concat(action.data)
    return { items }
  }
  case 'ITEM_ALREADY_ADDED': {
    state.items.map((item) => (
      item.name === action.data.name ? alert('Item already added') : item
    ))
    return { ...state }
  }
}
```

When I type into the `input another item` and then click **add**, it calls the second case statement (item already exists). tTis is working, however, I broke the add item case.

So I'm trying to do a ternary and I'm not sure what to put on the right-hand side of the `:` if the item isn't there. This is where I want to do my check and then call the other action.

So two questions:

1. How can I do this?
2. Is this the best place to be doing the ternary/check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question

you can do it like this

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_ITEM': {
      const items = [].concat(state.items).concat(action.data)
      return { ...state, items }
    }
// dont do the alert here, instead access the items array in your component using connect and mapStateToProps. do looing there and check whether it is already existing or not. depending on which dispatch action. you dont need to have ITEM_ALREADY_ADDED case.

    }
```

// your component and for your second question

```
    class A extends React.Component {
    add = () => {
    const {items} = this.props
    // write yout logic here and check whether the item is already availle
    //and accordingly dispatch the action
    } 
    render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
       </div>
    )

  }
}

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      items : state.yourreducrename.items,
    }
```

> Note : this is just higher level overview, please adjust the code
>   accordingly